# How to indicate radius (or size) of circle when it's defined as `\path node[shape=circle]at(x,y){}`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I need to change the size of the circle but using `radius` doesn't work here.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path node(ID1)[draw,shape=rectangle]{ID1};
\path node[draw=red,shape=circle]at(ID1.north){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's neither nor. If you want a circle of radius *exactly* 2pt, try `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path node(ID1)[draw,shape=rectangle]{ID1};
\path node[draw=red,shape=circle,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]at(ID1.north){};
\draw[blue] (ID1.north east) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several pgf keys that matter, which you can control by setting `minimum size` and `inner sep` appropriately. `inner sep` is, to a good approximation`if the radius is not "too small". If you want to control the radius very precisely, use`inner sep=0pt`and`minimum size=`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path node(ID1)[draw,shape=rectangle]{ID1};
 \path node[draw=red,shape=circle,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]at(ID1.north){};
 \draw[blue] (ID1.north east) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]